# fluent nhibernate mapping many to many configuration error

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I struggle with the HasManyToMany method in the fluent nhibernate world. Here is my "database" application. In this database I have some test data. Now I want to ask the database via the Query method which User can use what for a Application.
[image]

### here are my model classes:

```
    public class Application
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }

        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<User> User { get; set; }

        public Application()
        {
            User = new List<User>();
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }

        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Application> Application { get; set; }

        public User()
        {
            Application = new List<Application>();
        }
    }
```

### and here is the mapping code:

```
    public class ApplicationMap : ClassMap<Application>
    {
        public ApplicationMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.Name);
            HasManyToMany(x => x.User)
               .Table("Access")
               .ParentKeyColumn("user_fk")
               .ChildKeyColumn("id")
               .Cascade.All();
        }
    }

    public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
    {
        public UserMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.Name);
            HasManyToMany(x => x.Application)
               .Table("Access")
               .ParentKeyColumn("application_fk")
               .ChildKeyColumn("id")
               .Cascade.All();
        }
    }
```

here are my data access method:

> ```
>     public static List<Application> SelectApplicationByUser(int userId)
>     {
>         var session = SessionManager.CurrentSession;
>         return session.Query<Application>().Where(x => x.User.Any(y => y.Id == userId)).ToList();  
>     }
> ```

Now I get the error unknown column user id. Can someone give me some kick, I have search so long and used many approaches, but nothing has worked. What is wrong with my mapping definiton? Or maybe my Linq statement is also wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1321519/1258536

Comment: yeah, I have try this: The methods which start with with are old, is my definition ParentKey, ChildKey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Parent column is where to search for holder id (application). the child is where is the reference id to be searched in user table.

```
public ApplicationMap()
{
   Id(x => x.Id);
   Map(x => x.Name);
   HasManyToMany(x => x.User)
       .Table("Access")
       .ParentKeyColumn("application_fk")
       .ChildKeyColumn("user_fk")
       .Cascade.All();
}
```

And similar for user

```
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Application)
           .Table("Access")
           .ParentKeyColumn("user_fk")
           .ChildKeyColumn("application_fk")
           .Inverse()            // this is essential
           .Cascade.All();
    }
```

NOTE: One of the collection must be mapped as `Inverse()`. That will correctly solve issues with the order of insert, update...

> NOTE2: Very important note. The Cascade all is most likely not needed.
>   In many to many relations, the pair table is handled always. The
>   cascade in this case means do change all referenced user entities,
>   when changing the application.

Read here more: [23.2. Author/Work](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#example-mappings-authorwork)