# Fluent NHibernate Returning Duplicates with Many to Many Mappings

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using NHibernate with Fluent mapping and having an issue with duplicate entries when I join against a many-to-many relationship.  My simple example below has two classes, PurchaseOrder and Product.  A PurchaseOrder can have many Products and a Product can be part of many PurchaseOrders.

When I attempt to retrieve a PurchaseOrder and it's Products, I get the same PurchaseOrder repeated for each Product.  (So if a PurchaseOrder has 5 Products I will see the same PurchaseOrder in my result 5 times.  Each with all 5 Products.)

Here is my setup:

### Tables

```
PurchaseOrder
    OrderID  OrderDate
    1        2013-01-01
    2        2013-01-02

Product
    ProductID   Name
    1           Widget
    2           Thing

OrderProducts
    OrderID ProductID
    1       1
    1       2
    2       1
    2       2
```

### Classes

```
public class PurchaseOrder
{
    public virtual int OrderID { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public virtual int ProductID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set;  }
    public virtual IList<PurchaseOrder> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

### Mappings

```
public class PurchaseOrderMapping : ClassMap<PurchaseOrder>
{
    public PurchaseOrderMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.OrderID, "OrderID");
        Map(x => x.OrderDate, "OrderDate");

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Products)
            .Table("OrderProducts")
            .Schema("dbo")
            .ParentKeyColumn("OrderID")
            .ChildKeyColumn("ProductID");

        Schema("dbo");
        Table("PurchaseOrder");
    }
}

public class ProductMapping : ClassMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMapping ()
    {
        Id(x => x.ProductID, "ProductID");
        Map(x => x.Name, "Name");

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Orders)
            .Table("OrderProducts")
            .Schema("dbo")
            .ParentKeyColumn("OrderID")
            .ChildKeyColumn("ProductID")
            .Inverse();

        Schema("dbo");
        Table("Product");
    }
}
```

### QueryOver

```
var orderList = session.QueryOver<PurchaseOrder>()
               .JoinQueryOver<Product>(o => o.Products)
               .List();
```

I expect orderList to have 2 PurchaseOrders, **but it actually has 4**.  The object corresponding to OrderID=1 is repeated, as is OrderID=2

```
foreach(var o in orderList) { Console.WriteLine(o.OrderID); }

Output:
1
1
2
2
```

To take it further, if I compare the objects with the same ID, they are the same object.

```
System.Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(orderList[0], orderList[1]));
System.Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(orderList[2], orderList[3]));

Output:
True
True
```

**Why is NHibernate duplicating the objects in the result?  How do I exclude them and get just my list of 2 Orders, with their corresponding 2 Products each?**

Comment: your mapping goes to .Table("OrderProducts") in both maps, is this intended?

Comment: It is intended, unless I am misunderstanding something (which is definitely possible).  The OrderProducts table is the relationship table that maps the PurchaseOrder to Products, and is what makes it a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you have the parent and child keys wrong in the ProductMapping. Your query returns multiple results due to the join. You need to use a transformer to return only distinct root entities:

```
var orderList = session.QueryOver<PurchaseOrder>()
           .JoinQueryOver<Product>(o => o.Products)
           .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
           .List();
```

Note that if you only want to eager fetch the products collection, you can specify that using Fetch:

```
var orderList = session.QueryOver<PurchaseOrder>()
           .Fetch(o => o.Orders).Eager
           .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
           .List();
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for.  I am a little surprised that distinct is not the default behavior, since NHibernate does know that the objects are the same.  But whatever works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For some reason `session.QueryOver<T>` doesn't return a distinct result out of the box, you'll have to explicitly define it either by a result transformer or by Linq `.Distinct()`

```
var orderList = session.QueryOver<PurchaseOrder>()
    .Fetch(p => p.Products).Eager
    .List()
    .Distinct();
```

or

```
var orderListFetch = session.QueryOver<PurchaseOrder>()
    .Fetch(p => p.Products).Eager
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
    .List();
```

Alternatively you could also use the Nhibernate.Linq: `session.Query<T>` interface, this one does actually return a distinct result per default:

```
var linqQuery = session.Query<PurchaseOrder>()
    .Fetch(p => p.Products).ToList();
```

All 3 queries do generate almost the exact same SQL statements which all would return 4 rows, **because it uses left outer joins**...

The result will always be transformed to a distinct result set in memory!

*Test Setup*

I've slightly changed your code, switched the parent and child keys.
For inserting/update/delete child records, you might also want to keep the cascade

```
public class PurchaseOrder
{
    public virtual int OrderID { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public virtual int ProductID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<PurchaseOrder> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseOrderMapping : ClassMap<PurchaseOrder>
{
    public PurchaseOrderMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.OrderID, "OrderID");
        Map(x => x.OrderDate, "OrderDate");

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Products)
            .Table("OrderProducts")
            .Schema("dbo")
            .ParentKeyColumn("ProductID")
            .ChildKeyColumn("OrderID")
            .Cascade.All();

        Schema("dbo");
        Table("PurchaseOrder");
    }
}

public class ProductMapping : ClassMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.ProductID, "ProductID");
        Map(x => x.Name, "Name");

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Orders)
            .Table("OrderProducts")
            .Schema("dbo")
            .ParentKeyColumn("OrderID")
            .ChildKeyColumn("ProductID")
            .Inverse();

        Schema("dbo");
        Table("Product");
    }
}
```

Comment: That OrderProducts table in my example is the relationship table you mention.  Using that, and copying the rest of your mapping I still get the same issue even with the Fetch.  And it's true from either side of the relationship.  (QueryOver<PurchaseOrder> or QueryOver<Product> both have duplicates in their respective lists.)

Comment: @JoeG you're right, if I fetch the sub items the query returns 4 elements instead of 2, but this seems to be normal because the generated query actually returns 4 rows...
Just do `List().Distinct()` should solve it... Only running session.QueryOver<PurchaseOrder>().List(); gives me 2 results, but then, all sub items are lazy loaded of cause

Comment: Your Distinct() is a LINQ call though.  Is there not a direct NHibernate approach to do the same thing?  I get that the the query results are multiple rows, but if it was smart enough to recognize they are the same object, why can't it do the DISTINCT natively?  Seems like using LINQ to do it is a work around and not the direct solution.

Comment: @JoeG actually you have to do it with distinct somehow. Eigther you define a ResultTransformer, or use the Distinct, in both cases the result will be transformed after it has been retrieved from the database...
Or you use the Nhibernate.Linq session.Query instead of session.QueryOver, this will do it automatically for some reason...

session.Query<PurchaseOrder>().Fetch(p=>p.Products).ToList();

Comment: @JoeG I updated the answer, actually all 3 different queries do almost exactly the same. There are just different methods to get a distinct result...

Comment: Thanks.  Jamie beat you to it, but the Transformer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321416/fluent-nhibernate-hasmanytomany-mapping), I see your `ProductMapping` should swap `ParentKeyColumn` and `ChildKeyColumn` values, like:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Orders)
        .Table("OrderProducts")
        .Schema("dbo")
        .ParentKeyColumn("ProductID")
        .ChildKeyColumn("OrderID")
        .Inverse();
```

I'm in doubt about the usage of [`.Inverse()`](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#example-mappings-authorwork) in this case. I would bet that it just tells NHibernate that the `ProductMapping` is not responsible for the relationship (not sure about this though).

Comment: Swapping the Parent/Child key has no impact that I can see.  You are right about Inverse.  It tells NHibernate that the PurchaseOrder is responsible for saving (which makes sense because you expect an Order to add Products but not a Product to add Orders).

Answer (score 0):

The mapping of `Order` is correct you must change only the mapping of `Product` swapping as this:

```
.ParentKeyColumn("ProductID") // product is the Parent
.ChildKeyColumn("OrderID") // order is the child
```

About the `Inverse` part why you need that?

Comment: Changing the Parent/Child order in any combination seems to have no effect on the result.  The Inverse is required to "make the other side of the relationship responsible for saving".  (Orders can add Products but Products shouldn't add Orders.)